# Sort order file when sent to xml

Tags: mysql, xml

I have the following statement:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' order by reporttime desc limit 30 ";
```

It works but I am feeding the results to a xml file that needs the order reversed to what is displayed.

The display looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" ?> 
- <markers>
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.1088" lng="-64.8708" datetime="2012-01-20 20:26:33"     course="" Speed="28" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.1038" lng="-64.8633" datetime="2012-01-20 20:25:23" course="" Speed="26" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.1038" lng="-64.8625" datetime="2012-01-20 20:25:19" course="" Speed="16" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.1037" lng="-64.862" datetime="2012-01-20 20:25:11" course="" Speed="10" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.1035" lng="-64.8622" datetime="2012-01-20 20:25:05" course="" Speed="14" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.0978" lng="-64.86" datetime="2012-01-20 20:24:18" course="" Speed="18" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.0943" lng="-64.8407" datetime="2012-01-20 20:21:40" course="" Speed="40" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
  <marker call="VE9SC-9" lat="46.0977" lng="-64.8178" datetime="2012-01-20 20:19:08" course="" Speed="12" alt="" Icon="/P" /> 
 </markers>
```

The newest being listed on the top, what I need is the oldest listed on the top.

I have tried desc & ASC but that will not work what needs to be done ? I have looked on-line and I can not find an answer.

Thanks
Stephen

Comment: So you have tried "order by reporttime ASC"? That should work...

Comment: the problem then is it grabs the oldest records the sorts them.

Comment: I need the last thirty reconds entered in the database them have them displayed by oldest first from the thirty records. ASC works but I get the old records but the newest of the old in still on top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL does the ordering first and then limits the results. That is why you would get the 30 oldest results. You need to do a subquery such that ordering happens *after* you have pulled the 30 newest records:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM aprstrack WHERE callsignSSID = 'VE9SC-9' order by reporttime desc limit 30) ORDER BY reporttime ASC";
```

Comment: Thank you that did not work as stated but I did help and I was able to make it work. I just had to remove the first select * From then it work.

Comment: I thak you very must for all your help, I was looking at this and could not get it to work, but with your help it is working. Thanks again.